# Re-render a template after a model is added to a collection

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I have a list of messages that are associated with a model:

```
App.User = DS.Model.extend({

  displayName: DS.attr('string'),
  email: DS.attr('string'),
  firstName: DS.attr('string'),
  lastName: DS.attr('string'),
  location: DS.attr('string'),
  messages: DS.hasMany('message', { async: true })

});

App.Message = DS.Model.extend({

  user: DS.belongsTo('user'),
  recipient: DS.belongsTo('user'),
  createdAt: DS.attr('isodate'),
  updatedAt: DS.attr('isodate'),
  fullText: DS.attr('string'),
  subject: DS.attr('string')

});
```

I render a user's messages like so:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="profile">
    <form class="new-message navbar-form" role="search" {{action "sendMessage" on="submit"}}>
         {{textarea valueBinding="newMessageText" rows="3" placeholder="Send a Message"}}
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block" style="margin-top: 10px">Submit</button>
    </form>
    {{#each message in messages}}
    <div class="message text-left">
        <div class="page-header clearfix">
            <p class="created-at">{{format-date message.createdAt}}</p>
            <img class="profile-pic" src="http://lorempixel.com/24/24/people" alt="profile" class="img-rounded">
            <p class="subject">{{message.subject}}</p>
        </div>
        <p class="full-text">{{message.fullText}}</p>
    </div>
    {{/each}}
</script>
```

When a new message is submitted using the form above, a new messages is added to the store and saved to the server.  The problem is that the list of messages is not re-rendered to include the newly-added message when the `save` is performed:

```
App.UserController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({

  newMessageText: '',

  actions: {

    sendMessage: function() {
      var that = this;
      var message = this.get('store').createRecord('message', {
        fullText: this.newMessageText,
        recipient: this.get('model')
      });
      message.save().then(function () {
        // A new message is added to the store linked to the user, but the
        // newly-saved message is not added to the template.
        that.set('newMessageText', '');
      });
    }

  }

});
```

What's the proper way to ensure new messages added to the store force my template to re-render?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an ArrayController for the messages list, or an [Ember.Array](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Array.html) (depends on your needs). You need either of those because you want your object to be *observable* so that the auto-updating mechanism, that the templates use, can react to the changes.